# What is the use for this file pk_backend_zypp under /var/log and can I truncate it on OpenSuse Linux 13.2 (Harlequin)

Tags: linux, opensuse, zypper

I am running `opensuse 13.2` and I have this file `pk_backend_zypp` under the `/var/log` directory which keeps growing.

What could be the use of this file and can I truncate (zerorize) it without causing harm.

The files consuming up space that I would like to reclaim.

```
-rw-r----- 1 user group pk_backend_zypp
-rw-r----- 1 user group pk_backend_zypp-1
```

Comment: I truncated the files and so far, no issues seen with the server. Probably, it is no harm truncating or zerorizing those files

Answer (score 1):

It's "PackageKit (with libzypp back-end) log files." -> https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/tuning/html/book-tuning/cha-tuning-logfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

I truncated the files and no issues seen with the server. No harm truncating or zerorizing those files.